# ASP Gridview that selects multiple rows and retrieves the value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to trying to allow the user to select multiple rows of my grid and then those selected values display in the text box. I can get one value into the textbox and able to select one row. How can I change what I already have to allow multiple selections? I tried whats posted below thinking adding a new instance of the object would allow me to see both values in the textbox but it just repeats the first selected value.

```
protected void dropdeadGridView_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = dropdeadGridView.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
    GridViewRow row1 = dropdeadGridView.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
}
protected void dropdeadGridView_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = dropdeadGridView.SelectedRow;
    GridViewRow row1 = dropdeadGridView.SelectedRow;
    IDTextBox.Text = row.Cells[1].Text + "," + row1.Cells[1].Text;
    loadnumTextBox.Text = row.Cells[2].Text + "," + row1.Cells[2].Text;

}
```

ASP code

```
<asp:GridView ID="dropdeadGridView" runat="server" Height="300px" 
        Width="650px" BackColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" 
        CellPadding="3" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor = "Yellow" 
        onselectedindexchanging="dropdeadGridView_SelectedIndexChanging"
        autogenerateselectbutton="true" selectedindex="0" 
        onselectedindexchanged="dropdeadGridView_SelectedIndexChanged1" >
        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BorderStyle="Inset" BorderColor="Red" ForeColor="Red" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: If you would like to select multiple rows  I would add a check box to the gridview. The user checks the boxes and that will indicate which rows are selected. Afterwards populate the textboxes with the rows values.

Comment: @snowYetis so checkbox instead of select link?

Comment: I cannot find anything online about using a select link to grab multiple rows. I do not want to say it is not possible, but I do know I have done this with checkboxes. Can you post your ASP code?

Comment: @snowYetis yes give me a sec

Comment: @snowYetis it has been updated

Comment: Ok.. I have a solution typed out. But one last thing, what instiates the copy of the gridview rows data to the textbox? Is this real time or will this have a button click or something else?

Comment: @snowYetis it is on page load then I bind again on button click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using ASP.Net web forms I would recommend creating an  placinig the check box control inside of there then the user clicks the checkbox on the rows they would like to select. In the code behind within the butto click event find the rows by looking for the checkbox.checked property. Afterwards read the desired cells data and append it to your textboxes.

```
   <asp:GridView ID="yourGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    DataSourceID="YourSource" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="YourCheckBox" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ModifiedDate" HeaderText="ModifiedDate" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

### Here is updated Code Behind##

If you are not comfy with JQuery then go with this.

```
    protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)chk.Parent.Parent;
txtBox.Text = GridView1.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();


}
```

### REVISION - A JQuery Solution

However, I think the easiest way of doing this based on your requirements is by using JQuery.

First add a jquery script to your project. Go to Jquery.com pull down the latest script if your project does not have it already. In the head of your page mark up add the ref.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="The source of your JS file"></script>
```

Then at the end of your body write your JQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    // Capture the click event by going through the gridview > tablerow > tabledisplay >        `lastly the checkbox - grab the click event.
 $('#GrdViewID' tr td  
 input[id*="chkSelected"]`[type=checkbox]:checked').on('click',function () {
          $('#txtBox').text($(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(2).text());
     });
</script>
```

Comment: How about JQuery then?

Comment: Haven't payed with it much but I'm game to try!

Comment: This sounds perfect for JQuery. You wont have to post back and it will take a couple lnes of code. I will post a revision. Give me 1 sec.

Comment: Don't have a checkbox1_CheckChanged... just selectedindexchanged

Comment: Sorry it has been a while since I worked on WebForms. I would go the Jquery route then. You will alleviate postbacks and the row data will assign to the textbox when the users checks the box.

Comment: Lol alright man sounds simple enough and there not my favorite either.

Comment: I borrowed that code from a past project. Let me know if you have trouble getting it to work. I can edit the answer so it is more tailored to your code.

Comment: Well first off that bottom all goes into jscript file?

Comment: If you are not crunched for time, take a time out and go through this quick class on JQuery. It is a great and fast tutorial.
https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-jquery